# oracle execute immediate not executing

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle (11gr2) and I have the following script:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        source varchar2(1);

    BEGIN
        dbms_output.enable;


        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP VIEW SP_AD;';
            SELECT SOURCE INTO source FROM map_switch WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
            IF source = 'A' 
                THEN 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SP_AD_B;';
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'RENAME TABLE SP_AD_A TO SP_AD;';
                ELSE 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SP_AD_A;';
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'RENAME TABLE SP_AD_B TO SP_AD;';
            END IF;
            COMMIT WORK;
                    dbms_output.put_line('SP_AD table issue fixed');
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    dbms_output.put_line('Exception, rolling back transaction, SP_AD not resolved.');
                    ROLLBACK WORK;
        END;        
    END;
END;
/
```

Essentially, its determining which table to drop, then it drops the view and renames the other table.

If I run the statements individually, it works perfectly well, but in the script above, it returns procedure executed successfully but nothing was executed.

I'm suspecting that its rolling back for some odd reason, but I'm hesitating to execute it without the rollback in place (these tables have in excess of 300,000 records).

Can someone tell me what's wrong and also, is there something wrong with my exception block?

Comment: Remove terminating semicolon from dynamic queries!

Comment: you cannot rollback DDL statements. They don't need COMMIT either.

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong with your `EXCEPTION` block is that you a catch all exceptions (`WHEN OTHERS`) but you do not write the message to `dbms_output` or reraise it.  Adding a line such as `dbms_output.put_line('Error was ' || SQLERRM);` to your `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` block would tell you what the problem was.

Comment: @LukeWoodward how would that look like?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff the ones within the quotes or out?

Comment: Why do you retrieve just the first record from `map_switch`? That's a code smell right there as it is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out by commenters, there are a few reasons why your code isn't working as expected.

Firstly, don't use semicolons inside the strings that you pass to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, as doing that will give you an ORA-00911 'invalid character' error:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SP_AD_B;';
  3  END;
  4  /
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

After running this, you can then verify that the table still exists:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM SP_AD_B;

no rows selected
```

(I don't have your table `SP_AD_B`, so I just created one named `SP_AD_B` with a single integer column in it.  I didn't bother putting any data in it.)

If you remove the semicolon inside the string, not the one outside, it works:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SP_AD_B';
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM SP_AD_B;
SELECT * FROM SP_AD_B
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Now that the table's gone, we get an error attempting to query it.

Hopefully, this should allow you to fix your script so that it works and drops the relevant tables.

But why weren't you getting any helpful information in your output message?  Well, let's recreate the `SP_AD_B` table, and reintroduce the semicolon, and try dropping the table again, but with an `EXCEPTION` handler similar to yours:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SP_AD_B;';
  3  EXCEPTION
  4    WHEN OTHERS THEN
  5      dbms_output.put_line('Exception, rolling back transaction, SP_AD not resolved.');
  6  END;
  7  /
Exception, rolling back transaction, SP_AD not resolved.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In this case, we got an error message telling us something went wrong, so the table wasn't dropped.  But *what* went wrong?  There are thousands of errors that Oracle can report, and it can be difficult to guess what the problem is without knowing the error message.

There are a number of approaches you can take here.  Firstly, you could write the error message, in `SQLERRM` to `dbms_output`:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SP_AD_B;';
  3  EXCEPTION
  4    WHEN OTHERS THEN
  5      dbms_output.put_line('Exception, rolling back transaction, SP_AD not resolved.');
  6      dbms_output.put_line('Error message was: ' || SQLERRM);
  7  END;
  8  /
Exception, rolling back transaction, SP_AD not resolved.
Error message was: ORA-00911: invalid character

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You can also use [`dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_util.htm#i1003874) to return the current stacktrace as a string, if you so wish.  That might help you figure out where the error came from.

Alternatively, you can reraise the exception.   Using `RAISE` on its own in an `EXCEPTION` handler reraises the current exception:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SP_AD_B;';
  3  EXCEPTION
  4    WHEN OTHERS THEN
  5      dbms_output.put_line('Exception, rolling back transaction, SP_AD not resolved.');
  6      RAISE;
  7  END;
  8  /
Exception, rolling back transaction, SP_AD not resolved.
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

However, given the fact that your `EXCEPTION` handler isn't really doing anything helpful, the best approach is quite probably to get rid of it altogether.

Your exception handler doesn't achieve anything because you can't commit or rollback DDL statements such as `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP` or `TRUNCATE`.  Each of these statements issues a `COMMIT` immediately before and after it runs.  If a `DROP` succeeds but a `RENAME` fails, you can't get the dropped table back by rolling back a transaction.  I'd recommend getting rid of your `COMMIT WORK` and `ROLLBACK WORK` statements.

Finally, commenter Jeffrey Kemp noticed this line:

```
SELECT SOURCE INTO source FROM map_switch WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

This assigns into a variable named `source` the value of the column `SOURCE` *from some arbitrary row of the table `map_switch`*.  It could be any row; as you haven't specified any ordering, Oracle is free to order the rows of `map_switch` however it likes.

If there's only one row in the table, then it's clear which row you'll get back.  However, if this is the case, why specify `ROWNUM = 1`?  Does the table have more than one row and is the `ROWNUM = 1` part is just there to silence an 'exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows' error?

You would be better off doing something like the following:

```
SELECT SOURCE INTO source
  FROM (SELECT SOURCE FROM map_switch ORDER BY some_column)
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

I don't know what columns there are in your  `map_switch` table, so I've just used `some_column` above as a placeholder for one of them.  Choose a column that has unique values, if possible.

Note that we can't simply do `SELECT ... WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY some_column` as that would apply the `ROWNUM = 1` clause before doing the sorting, and there's not a lot of point sorting a single row as there's only one order it can be returned in.

Comment: Thank you! Now THAT is a text book answer which should be the template for all answers on SO.  I wish I could upvote that even more